# OpenVPN connect to azure VNET: Peer certificate verification failure

Tags: azure, vnet, azure-vpn

I'm trying to configure VPN Gateway to provide access to VNET in Azure. For this I used following documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/create-routebased-vpn-gateway-cli

In the result I wrote following bash script for creating required services in Azure:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -e

eval $(grep -v -e '^#' .env | xargs -I {} echo export \'{}\')

az network vnet subnet create \
    --vnet-name $VNET_NAME \
    --name GatewaySubnet \
    --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME \
    --address-prefix "10.0.17.0/27"

az network public-ip create \
    --name "${VNET_NAME}-vpn-ip" \
    --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME \
    --allocation-method Dynamic

az network vnet-gateway create \
    --name $VNET_GETEWAY_NAME \
    --location $VNET_LOCATION \
    --public-ip-address "${VNET_NAME}-vpn-ip" \
    --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME \
    --vnet $VNET_NAME \
    --gateway-type Vpn \
    --sku VpnGw1 \
    --vpn-type RouteBased \
    --address-prefixes "172.16.201.0/24" \
    --vpn-gateway-generation Generation1 \
    --client-protocol OpenVPN \
    --root-cert-name RootCert \
    --root-cert-data caCert.pem \
    --vpn-auth-type Certificate \
    --no-wait
```

For generation of self-signed certificates I use strongSwan and openssl by documentation from following topics:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-certificates-point-to-site-linux

https://mariadb.com/docs/xpand/security/data-in-transit-encryption/create-self-signed-certificates-keys-openssl/

Сorrectness of created certificates I checked by openssl verify util

[image]

Next step was Download VPN Client for OpenVPN

[image]

After that I filled in user  and  blocks in vpnconfig.ovpn

```
# P2S client certificate
# Please fill this field with a PEM formatted client certificate
# Alternatively, configure 'cert PATH_TO_CLIENT_CERT' to use input from a PEM certificate file. <cert>
# Content of userCert.pem or client-cert.pem files
</cert>

# P2S client certificate private key
# Please fill this field with a PEM formatted private key of the client certificate.
# Alternatively, configure 'key PATH_TO_CLIENT_KEY' to use input from a PEM key file.
<key>
# Content of userKey.pem or clientKey.pem files
</key>
```

For running OpenVPN connection I used Windows  OpenVPN client. When used vpnconfig.ovpn to connect to Azure I get message error: Peer certificate verification failure.

OpenVPN logs

```
[Aug 4, 2023, 11:27:46] OpenVPN core 3.git::d3f8b18b win x86_64 64-bit built on Feb  7 2023 16:08:10
[Aug 4, 2023, 11:27:46] Frame=512/2048/512 mssfix-ctrl=1250
[Aug 4, 2023, 11:27:46] UNUSED OPTIONS 6 [resolv-retry] [infinite] 7 [nobind] 10 [persist-key] 11 [persist-tun] 15 [log] [openvpn.log] 16 [verb] [3] 
[Aug 4, 2023, 11:27:46] EVENT: RESOLVE 
[Aug 4, 2023, 11:27:46] EVENT: WAIT 
[Aug 4, 2023, 11:27:46] WinCommandAgent: transmitting bypass route to 52.191.28.72 {    "host" : "52.191.28.72",    "ipv6" : false }  
[Aug 4, 2023, 11:27:46] Connecting to [azuregateway-651a0077-6bec-43a5-9738-fb84b4090d03-55fa834d773d.vpn.azure.com]:443 (52.191.28.72) via TCPv4 
[Aug 4, 2023, 11:27:46] EVENT: CONNECTING 
[Aug 4, 2023, 11:27:46] Tunnel Options:V4,dev-type tun,link-mtu 1523,tun-mtu 1500,proto TCPv4_CLIENT,keydir 1,cipher AES-256-GCM,auth [null-digest],keysize 256,tls-auth,key-method 2,tls-client 
[Aug 4, 2023, 11:27:46] Creds: UsernameEmpty/PasswordEmpty 
[Aug 4, 2023, 11:27:46] Peer Info: IV_VER=3.git::d3f8b18b IV_PLAT=win IV_NCP=2 IV_TCPNL=1 IV_PROTO=30 IV_CIPHERS=AES-256-GCM:AES-128-GCM:CHACHA20-POLY1305 IV_AUTO_SESS=1 IV_GUI_VER=OCWindows_3.3.7-2979 IV_SSO=webauth,openurl,crtext
[Aug 4, 2023, 11:27:47] Transport Error: OpenSSLContext::SSL::read_cleartext: BIO_read failed, cap=2576 status=-1: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed 
[Aug 4, 2023, 11:27:47] EVENT: CERT_VERIFY_FAIL OpenSSLContext::SSL::read_cleartext: BIO_read failed, cap=2576 status=-1: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed⏎[Aug 4, 2023, 11:27:47] EVENT: DISCONNECTED
```

Anybody have any thoughts how I can fix it?

I would be grateful for any advice!

I used 2 different ways to generate certificates (mentioned above) but no one give me the same result. I found similar issue but provided advices did not help to solve problem.

[Azure VPN / OpenVPN(SSL) Peer certificate verification failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72834230/azure-vpn-openvpnssl-peer-certificate-verification-failure)

In the result OpenVPN return the same message error: Peer certificate verification failure.

Answer (score 0):

In OpenVPN ***"Peer certificate verification failure"*** this error usually occurs if the client certificate failed to validate the certificate presented by the VPN server or if certificate is not trusted by the client any mismatch between the certificate and the server hostname.

***To resolve this issue,*** check the certificate presented by the VPN server is signed by a trusted root CA.

```
openssl s_client -connect azuregateway-651a0077-6bec-43a5-9738-fb84b4090d03-55fa834d773d.vpn.azure.com:443
 #Check the hostname are matches the hostname on the server certificate.
openssl s_client -connect azuregateway-651a0077-6bec-43a5-9738-fb84b4090d03-55fa834d773d.vpn.azure.com:443 | openssl x509 -noout -subject
```

Make sure in the client config file (vpnconfig.ovpn) see if the root CA is included in the "ca" section like **`ca caCert.pem`**

Alternatively, to connect VPN using point to site in OpenVPN check the below:

Configure virtual network gateway:

[image]

Using this url  login with global administrator and grant admin consent for your organization.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?client_id=41b23e61-6c1e-4545-b367-cd054e0ed4b4&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://portal.azure.com&nonce=1234&prompt=admin_consent
```

[image]

In point to site, selected OpenVPN in Authentication type you can use Active directory or [client certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-certificates-point-to-site) using powershell

[image]

```
Tenant    - https://login.microsoftonline.com/<AzureADTenantID>/
Audience  - 41b23e61-6c1e-4545-b367-cd054e0ed4b4
Issuer    - https://sts.windows.net/{AzureADTenantID}/
```

Now,  download the VPN clinet file and extract it.  install [**Azure VPN**](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/azure-vpn-client/9NP355QT2SQB?hl=en-us&gl=us) client from microsoft store and import your Azure vpn file `azurevpnconfig` file like below:

When I connected with my account vpn is connected successfully like below:

[image]

***Reference***:

[Configure Azure AD tenant and settings for P2S VPN connections: Azure AD authentication: OpenVPN - Azure VPN Gateway | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/openvpn-azure-ad-tenant)